# Замена перевода строки на <br />

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Доброй!
Есть функция, которая выводит в div текст,вводимы в textarea

```
function text (input, output) {
        var txtArea = document.getElementById(input);
        txtArea.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            var div = document.getElementById(output);
            if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
                txtArea.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,'<br />');
            }
                div.innerHTML = txtArea.value;
        })
    }
```

Но почему то перевод строки не заменяется на <br />
Помогите. народ!

Answer (score 0):

Метод replace возвращает значение, поэтому используйте возвращенное значение:

```
txtArea.value = txtArea.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,'<br />');
```